# jquery ui buttons show and hide in dialog box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have appended to my dialog box 3 buttons and inside of my dialog box I have 3 tabs and I would like show and hide the buttons in function of the clicked tab

the code for dialog looks as it follows

```
        $('a.open_dialog_edit').click(function(e) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        var tabsDiv=$('<div />').appendTo('body').load($(this).attr('href'),function(){
        //$('#tabs').tabs();


        var editor = $('.textarea').wysihtml5().data("wysihtml5").editor.setValue(getCustomText($('select#state').val(), $('input#contactname.required').val()));

        var dialog = $('#tabs').tabs(
                {
                    select: function(ev, ui) {
                        //Setup Buttons to each Tab
                        switch(ui.index) {
                        case 0:
                            $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find("button:contains('Email Senden')").hide();

                        break;

                        case 1:
                            $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find("button:contains('Speichern')").hide();

                        break;

                    }

                  }        
            }).dialog({ 

            title: $(this).attr('title'),
            modal: true,
            draggable: false,
            width: 800,
            position: 'top',
            buttons: 
                [{
                text: "Speichern",
                "class": "btn btn-primary",
                click: function () {
                    $.ajax({
                           type: "POST",
                           url: 'action.php',
                           data: $("#edit_form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                           success: function(data)
                           {
                               alert('Der Datensatz wurde gespeichert!'); // show response from the php script.
                           },
                            error:function(){

                               alert('Es gibt ein Fehler bei Daten übetragung!');

                            }
                         });
                },

            }, {
                text: "Email Senden",
                "class": "btn btn-primary",
                click: function () {
                    $.ajax({
                           type: "POST",
                           url: 'mailer.php',
                           data: $("#contactform").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                           success: function(data)
                           {
                               alert('Das Email wurde geschickt!'); // show response from the php script.
                           },
                           error:function(){

                               alert('Es gibt ein Fehler bei Daten übetragung!');

                            }
                         });
                },
                text: "Rechnung herunterladen",
                "class": "btn btn-primary",
                click: function() {

                    $.ajax({
                           type: "POST",
                           url: 'docsx.php',
                           data: $("#edit_form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                           success: function(data)
                           {

                               window.location.href ='rechnung.docx'; // show response from the php script.
                           },
                           error:function(){

                               alert('Es gibt ein Fehler bei Daten übetragung!');

                            }
                         });

                    }
            }],

            close: function() {
                tabsDiv.remove() // so I can reload again
                location.reload(true);
//              allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );


            },
        });

        $('select#state').on('change',function() {  
            $('ul.wysihtml5-toolbar').remove();
            alert($('select#state').val());
        $('.textarea').wysihtml5().data("wysihtml5").editor.setValue(getCustomText($('select#state').val(), $('input#contactname.required').val()));

    });

}); 

        return false;

});
```

an example would be: if the first tab is clicked than sen Email button should be hided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to first store the dialog element

```
var dialog = $('<div />').appendTo('body').load($(this).attr('href')).dialog({
```

Then check which tab is selected and find and hide the button.

```
$("#tabs").tabs(select:function(ev, ui){
    switch(ui.index) {
        case 1:
             dialog.find("button").show().filter(":contains('Send Email')").hide();
        break;

    }
    //alternatively can do this if the tabs and buttons are in the same order
    //lots of ways to do this...
    dialog.find("button").show().eq(ui.index).hide();
});
```

Update: you need to `show()` all the other buttons first before hiding the ones you want hidden.

Comment: hi thanks for your feedback I still don't know how to handle this issue if I put in a variable the dialog than it breaks everything

Comment: @user1659575, I don't see any errors in your code.  But you are not setting the tabs `select` option.  So I'm not sure what is broken for you?

Comment: Is almost working just the buttons on each click are not good rendered they disappear after 3 clicks I made an update on my code maybe you could help me

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that you need to show the hidden ones again first.  From your code it could look like this: `$('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find("button").show().filter(":contains('Email Senden')").hide();`

Comment: thanks a lot, and how to make it to initialize on dialog open, it's working just when a tab is already clicked

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a tabselect event and then access the tab using its index as shown below

```
   $('#tabs').bind('tabsselect',function(event, ui) {
            if(ui.index==2){
```

Put your send mail function on tab index you like operate with,an example is shown [here](http://fundapass.blogspot.in/2012/06/v-behaviorurldefaultvmlo_22.html)

Answer (score 0):

hiding and showing buttons can be achieved using css and jquery.  So for example, assign a unique class to each button when creating the dialog:

"class": "myButton1"

and then use jquery to show or hide:

$( '.myButton1' ).show();
$( '.myButton1' ).hide();